# can one pipeline pass parameters/arguments to another pipeline in aws sagemaker pipeline?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Doing some research/experimentation, I can trigger one pipeline from another pipeline in aws sagemaker via Eventbridge. is it possible to pass any parameters/values/arguments from one pipeline to another this way? say, i have a model building pipeline and I want to pass some model information to another pipeline , while triggering second pipeline after completion of first via eventbridge. is this possible or are there other ways to do this?

```
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["one pipeline"],
  "detail": {
    "currentPipelineExecutionStatus": ["Succeeded"],
    "previousPipelineExecutionStatus": ["Executing"],
    "pipelineArn": ["another-pipelineArn"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible using only EventBridge because the event does not contain pipeline parameters.

Your best bet would be a rule which triggers a Lambda. That Lambda then calls [ListPipelineParametersForExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ListPipelineParametersForExecution.html) and starts the second pipeline.